# What do several tildes (~) in URI mean?

Tags: html, url, uri, tilde

Considering I have URI like this:

`https://blablabla.com~home~dtbs~war/rest/downloads/`

Do all tildes represent home directory in this case? Can't really wrap my head around.

Comment: It would help to know where you are seeing this and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: It's in the code of project I was recently assigned to. More specifically there is a file model/url/services.json that has a structure like this    `{ "main":{ "configuration":"/blablabla.com~home~dtbs~war/rest/configuration", "download":"/blablabla.com~home~dtbs~war/rest/download", ... } }` Trying to understand what the final destination is.